# Ruby shortcut for "if (number in range) then..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Ruby shortcut for the following?

```
if (x > 2) and (x < 10)
  do_something_here
end
```

I thought I saw something to that effect, but cannot find a reference to it. Of course it's hard to lookup when you don't know what operator you're looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (3..9).include? x
  # whatever
end
```

As a sidenote, you can also use the triple equals operator for ranges:

```
if (3..9) === x
  # whatever
end
```

This lets you use them in case statements as well:

```
case x
  when 3..9
    # Do something
  when 10..17
    # Do something else
end
```

Comment: the triple equal is the shortcut I was looking for in this particular case! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
do_something if (3..9).include?( x )   # inclusive
do_something if (3...10).include?( x ) # inclusive start, exclusive end
```

See the [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html) class; you can read an introduction to them [hosted on my website](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_stdtypes.html%23ranges).

Comment: thank you very much. and your website is an exceptional resource I didn't know about!!

Comment: Careful with `Range#include?`. It evaluates *every* element in the range if the range is non-numeric. `("aaaaaa".."zzzzzz").include?("zzzzzz")` already takes **2 minutes** on my system. For integers, as the question states, it's no problem though.

Answer (score 5):

[Comparable#between?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Comparable.html#M002746)

```
do_something if x.between?(2, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
do_something if (3..9) === x
```

or

```
r = 3..9
if r === x
  . . .
```